# using transitionFromView with UIBarButtonItem customView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to flip the UIBarButtonItem in a navigation bar like Apple does in the iPod app to switch between track listings and album art.

I've dragged a button onto my navigation bar in interface builder which as I understand inserts a `UIBarButtonItem` with the button as its `customView`.

I'm using the following method to flip the button's customView but it ends up flipping the entire navigation bar!

I was hoping it was a weird emulator glitch but it's also happening on device.
Has anyone encountered this or see where I might be going wrong?

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.mapToggleBarButton.customView
                    toView:self.mapToggleBarButton.customView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Comment: I never found what was wrong, in the end I just didn't show an animated transition :(

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/197138

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is exactly the expected behavior for `UIView.transitionFromView` and `UIView.transitionWithView` ...

The animation is applied to the superview of the object that you're swapping between. You don't have to have a reference to it or anything - just a plain UIView to enclose the button and the flip should work as expected!

I've written a little about it here: http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `fromView` seems the same as the `toView` and that's why no animation. For example:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"On.png"]];
    [UIView transitionFromView:((UIButton*)refresh.customView).imageView toView:imgView duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       //
        UIButton *btn = ((UIButton*)refresh.customView);
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"On.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }];
```

Remember after flip animation, you should reset the `UIButton`, such as `image`, `action` and so on.